# MVVM Pattern in Master-Detail when editing details

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, master-detail

i have a ObservableCollection with some data. They are displayed as Master (ListBox) and Detail (some Labels). I use binding and IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to show the correct details to the selected master item. This works all fine. Now i want to edit some details (load different image). I implemeted this a a Button Command in the ViewModel.

But how do i know which item is selected (UI) in the ViewModel-layer ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really find the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property that useful in MVVM scenarios.
Just expose another SelectedItem property in the ViewModel.

```
public ItemType SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a value or Enumerable of values of your ViewModel to the ListBox's SelectedItems property.

```
SelectedItems="{Binding VMProperty}"
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you only want one item selected you need to set:

```
SelectionMode="Single"
SelectedItem="{Binding VMProperty}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, what you are looking for is the following

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding ObjectName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Plus under your ViewModel you have to declare the following

```
public YourObject ObjectName { get; set; }
```

Simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to detect which item in the collection is currently selected in the UI is to data bind a property of the same type as the items in the collection to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

Now, whenever the user selects a new item, the `SomeProperty` setter will be called:

```
public YourDataType SomeProperty
{
    get { return someProperty; }
    set
    {
        someProperty = value;
        // The value has just changed
    }
}
```